# How can users identify which of their iPhone/iPad apps are still only 32-bit (and therefore won't work in future)?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, 64-bit, 32-bit

Many iPhone/iPad users still use apps on their devices which are only 32-bit. These apps will not work in future if users upgrade to iOS 11, unless of course the apps themselves are updated to run natively in 64-bit.

This being the case, users may want to identify any important apps they have installed that will become useless if they upgrade to iOS 11 in a few months. By doing this users can prepare for the upgrade by:

- contacting the developer to confirm their future development plans, and
- finding alternative apps that will meet their needs

**How can users identify which of their currently installed apps are still only 32-bit?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 10.3 and above, users can:

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Swipe up and tap on **General**
3. Tap on **About**
4. Tap on **Applications**

A list will appear showing all of the apps you have installed that 
won’t run in 64-bit mode. Now you can tap on any of your important apps 
to determine if it is still available on the App Store. If…

- you get a message indicating it is not available, it’s quite likely 
  that the app is no longer supported. You should try contacting 
  the developer to check whether it will be updated.
- you’re taken directly to the App Store, then the app is still 
  available and you’ll need to contact the developer to confirm 
  their plans for 64-bit support.

This process is the recommended approach for ensuring you 
don’t get caught out when iOS 11 is released later in the year.